# Why is it that interval scales allow for addition/subtraction, but not multiplication/division?

Tags: scales, measurement

Why is it that interval scales allow for addition/subtraction, but not multiplication/division? If multiplication is just repeated addition (ditto for subtraction/division), why is it that interval scales only allow for the former pair of operations? I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me wrap my head around this. The answers provided to this very similar question aren't helpful at all ([Why multiplication and division are not allowed when using the interval scale?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82823/why-multiplication-and-division-are-not-allowed-when-using-the-interval-scale))

Comment: Here is a clue: 2 feet + 2 feet = 4 feet. The unit of the sum is the same as the unit of the terms. But (2 feet) * (2 feet) = 4 square feet, a new unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without getting into abstract algebra, the short, informal, answer is that addition / subtraction change where the point is located on the real line (or integers) *relative to where it was* before the operation, but multiplication / division change where the point is located *relative to 0*.

Adding, say, 20 to a number increases it by 20 on the real line, so you know in an absolute sense that it is 20 units larger.  Without knowing what the number is, though, you don't know whether that made it closer to or farther from 0.  For example, consider $x=-30$, $x=-5$, and $x=10$. Expressions like $y = x+20$ convey some information about the absolute position of $y$ relative to $x$, but not relative to $0$.

Multiplying a number by 20 always makes it 20 times farther away from 0 than it was before, but you don't know how much farther away in an absolute sense it is.  If it was 1, then it's 19 units greater after multiplication, but if it's -0.2, it's 0.4 units smaller after multiplication.  Expressions like $y=20x$ convey some information about the positions of $y$ and $x$ relative to $0$, but not about the absolute difference between $y$ and $x$.

Since interval scales don't have a well-defined 0, multiplication, although it can be done, isn't really meaningful, unless you have some very good application-specific reason for picking the 0 point you are working from.

As a further comment, it is a mistake to think that multiplication is just repeated addition.  How could you multiply $x$ by 1.4 if that were the case?  You would have to know how much $0.4x$ was to turn it into an addition problem, and in order to do that, you... need to be able to multiply $x$ by $0.4$.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! Could you recommend any books/sources where I can learn about the behaviour of these basic operations in much more depth? I was indoctrinated to think of multiplication as a repeated addition since my childhood, and it's hard to break the habit.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean; multiplication works out that way in a world with only integers - where division doesn't work, by the way -  which is what we always start out learning, but it isn't really.  My knowledge of modern real analysis books is pretty limited, having gotten out of school many years ago, but Mathematical Thinking: Problem-Solving and Proofs by D'angelo and West is a fun book I got for my daughter that covers the basics in a very well-laid out and clear way.  Well, "fun" to a certain type of person, I suppose.

Comment: Multiplication isn't *just* repeated addition, but that's the necessary core concept. Once you define multiplication that way on natural numbers, you can build on that notion to define multiplication on integers, then on rational numbers, real numbers, etc.